# Tex interpreter not exporting to eps matlab

Tags: matlab, export, interpreter, tex, eps

When I include greek symbols to x axis labels etc they appear fine in the matlab figure window however when I export to EPS there is just a blank space. If i export to PDF then it appears fine. What is going on?

For example I plot

```
figure(1)
xlabel('Crossing Angle [ \mu rad]','interpreter','tex','fontsize',20);
print(figure(1),'test','-depsc','-tiff','-r300')
```

[image: Image from the EPS save]

This is saved as an EPS file and then converted to a PDF by PDFviewer in mac

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: How do you export and what are the parameters? Have you tried `print(gcf,'myfig.eps','-depsc','-r300')`?

Comment: Nope still no greek symbols showing. I have recently updated to MacOS Sierra.. could this have something to do with it?

Comment: I just tried `print(gcf,'m.eps','-depsc')` and it works. You do not need `tiff` though.

Comment: You posted the `pdf`, but What about the `eps`? Is that correct?

Comment: I just edited the original comment. PDF viewer converts from EPS to PDF. It used to work before I did the update so I'm guessing something has gone wrong with the tex interpreter? The tiff command just enables me to see the graph as an icon. There is something wrong with the export to eps

Comment: Try printing directly to `pdf` and if the problem persists it shows that the update was the source of the issue. Otherwise, the `eps --> pdf` converter is causing the problem.

Comment: Yes you are correct. When i put the eps figure into a latex file its fine

Comment: @mcrouch: My assumption is that you need `$\mu$`.